# Add tags/categories to a WordPress post from WP-CLI

Tags: wordpress, bash, command-line-interface

I have a bash script that posts to WordPress. It does this fine, but I want to have it add tags to the posts. It uses [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org) and there doesn't seem to be a way to add tags to a post from it.

To clarify, I'm talking about post tags, not HTML tags.
Also, this bash script is being run on the same server that is hosting the WordPress site.

I also found [blogpost.py](http://zacharyflower.com/2012/12/23/how-to-post-to-wordpress-from-the-command-line/), however it doesn't seem to have a tag feature either.

From what I've read, I think I would be able to accomplish what I want using XML-RPC in some way, but I know almost nothing about it.

Here's the WP-CLI command I've been using. Which works, but doesn't add tags.

```
wp post create --post_title="This is the title" --post_content="This is the post" --post_status=future --porcelain
```

In desperation, I tried adding `--post_tags="these are tags"`, but it didn't work. I've been searching for the answer for days now.

I just want to be able to make a WordPress post, with tags and a category, from a cronjob. I'm familiar with bash, so that would be best, but if you know of any solutions using other languages, that's welcome also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you may know, post tags are a WordPress [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) (like categories) called `post_tag`.

You need a set of subcommands of [`wp post`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/), specifically [`wp post term`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/term/), to edit them.

You also need WP-CLI v0.18.0 or above – older versions don't have it.

In all these examples, *1* indicates the post ID.

**Add one or more tags to any existing tags**

Separate multiple tags with spaces (not commas.)

```
wp post term add 1 post_tag foo
Success: Added term.
```

**"Set" one or more tags**

This will replace (overwrite) any existing tags for the post.
You'd use this instead of `remove` followed by `add` (one fewer command necessary.)

Separate multiple tags with spaces.

```
wp post term set 1 post_tag bar baz
Success: Set terms.
```

**List current tags**

```
wp post term list 1 post_tag

+---------+------+------+----------+
| term_id | name | slug | taxonomy |
+---------+------+------+----------+
| 7       | bar  | bar  | post_tag |
| 5       | baz  | baz  | post_tag |
+---------+------+------+----------+
```

**Remove tag(s)**

```
wp post term remove 1316 post_tag baz
```

You can also use this for categories or any other taxonomy.

Comment: Hi William, could you possible comment on how this could be done in bulk (ie, if I need to set a category on a whole bunch of posts at once)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can now be done more simply. In today's latest version of wp-cli (2.4), [tags_input](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/create/) is an option of wp post create and update. You can therefore use

```
wp post create file --tags_input="Tag1,Tag2,Tag3.."
```

or

```
wp post update (postID) --tags_input="Tag1,Tag2,Tag3.."
```